# Do I need to JavaScript encode ASP.NET MVC with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I've recently read that I have to HTML encode and JavaScript encode user submitted data in order to prevent **[attacks](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/preventing-javascript-encoding-xss-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc)**.

- Do I need to JavaScript encode ASP.NET MVC with Bootstrap? (see specific example below)
- And if yes, how do I do it?

As I've understood, @Model.xxx automatically HTML encodes any data. However, I'm curious what happens in terms of encoding when I use various JS functionality in Bootstrap. Both for my specific case and in general.

Specifically I am using '[Popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)' with HTML content like this:

```
<button ... data-html="true" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-content="<strong>text</strong><br/> etc..." >
  Popover on left
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSS has nothing to do with Bootstrap. If you want to prevent XSS attacks in ASP.NET MVC. You may take a look on AntiForgeryToken. Phil Haacked has a [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/02/anatomy-of-csrf-attack.aspx/) regarding AntiForgeryToken

Comment: Hi sorry, maybe I phrased the question a bit incorrectly? I was referring to the type of attack mentioned in Jon Galloway's blog here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/preventing-javascript-encoding-xss-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc . Rephrased the question to remove the "XSS" part and included a link to the blog.